# Массив эквивалентен не массиву в JavaScript.

Tags: javascript

```
[] == ![] // -> true.
```

Может кто-то объяснить как это работает

Comment: и `==0`........

Comment: https://habrahabr.ru/post/171359/ вроде пункт 3 про это

Comment: @br3t, хотел ту же ссылку кинуть. Вообще на ночь такие вопросы лучше не задавать, а лучше их вообще никогда не задавать.

Comment: Ссылка на раздел спеки https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-abstract-equality-comparison

Comment: https://habrahabr.ru/company/mailru/blog/335292/#eto-fail - тут много подобных примеров

Comment: Наоборот лучше такие вопросы задавать чтобы понять как все работает =/ Смысл того что операция == - это нестрогое сравнение которое внутри пытается стайпкастить теплое с мягким к числу.Левая часть - пустой массив - тайпкастится к 0. Правая часть - false - тоже тайпкастится к 0.

Comment: Не читайте все эти "втф javascript", почитайте спеку пройдитесь карандашиком по алгоритму и все поймете.

Comment: @УткаУчитсяУму слева тайпкастится к 0, потому что массив пустой. А справа false, потому что массив - это объект, а они всегда true. и !true равно false. но почему слева не работает все по той же логике?

Comment: @StasTyrinov, потому что левое выражение - объект. Правое - булевое. Объект кастится к toPrimitive, то есть в данном случае к пустой строке. А пустая строка уже в число. То есть 0. [] => "" => 0. Правая же часть после вычисления выражения ![] булевая и кастится к числу. То есть false => 0. Еще раз, слева у нас тайпкаст Object => toPrimitive (string) => toNumber. Справа вычисление выражения (в котором Object => toBoolean), и результат этого выражения toNumber.

Comment: Смысл в того что универсальную логику каста чего попало во что попало организовать не так просто как кажется. Логика по которой оно работает описана в спецификации, в разделе ссылку на который я кинул.

Comment: Ну вы и намудрили =(О.о)=

Comment: @УткаУчитсяУму спасибо!

Comment: вот здесь https://habrahabr.ru/company/mailru/blog/335292/    - что за черт , JavaScript ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Описание алгоритма сравнения x == y http://es5.javascript.ru/x11.html#x11.9.3

```
[] == ![] 

typeof([]) - object
typeof(![]) - boolean
```

1. "7. Если Type(y) – Boolean, вернуть результат сравнения x == ToNumber(y)."
   1.1. ToNumber(y) 
    -> ToNumber(![]) 
    -> ToNumber(false) (почему false смотреть тут http://es5.javascript.ru/x11.html#x11.4.9)
    -> 0 (почему 0 смотреть тут http://es5.javascript.ru/x9.html#x9.3)
2. На данном этапе сравнение имеет вид x == 0 или [] == 0 и мы снова выполняем основной алгоритм сравнения:
   "9. Если Type(x) – Object и Type(y) –либо String, либо Number, вернуть результат сравнения ToPrimitive(x) == y."
3. ToPrimitive(x) -> ToPrimitive([]) (правило вычисления примитивов тут http://es5.javascript.ru/x9.html#x9.1,
   а для объектов тут http://es5.javascript.ru/x8.html#x8.12.8):

   "Если внутренний метод [[DefaultValue]] объекта O вызывается без подсказки, он ведет себя так, как если бы подсказка была Number, кроме случаев, когда O – объект Date (см. 15.9.6), и в этой ситуации он ведет себя, как если бы подсказка была String."
   И так как valueOf для массива возвращает пустой массив (подсказка Number, шаги 1-2), то к нему применяется toString (подсказка Number, шаги 3-4), что вернёт в итоге пустую строку "".
4. На данном этапе сравнение имеет вид "" == 0 и мы снова выполняем основной алгоритм сравнения: "5. Если Type(x) – String и Type(y) – Number, вернуть результат сравнения ToNumber(x) == y."
5. ToNumber("") == 0. ToNumber("") -> 0 так как "MV StringNumericLiteral ::: [empty] равно 0." отсюда http://es5.javascript.ru/x9.html#x9.3.1.
6. Наконец-то получем 0 == 0, что и даёт нам true.

Answer (score 4):

1. Объект всегда true, => не массив это false (логическое преобразование)
2. Получаем сравнение разных типов => применяется численное преобразование
3. Пустой массив преобразуется к 0, false тоже к 0

Answer (score 3):

**В JavaScript `array` массив представлен в виде объекта**

```js
console.log(typeof({}));
console.log(typeof([]));
```

**Сравнивать обьекты и функции в джаваскрипте не возможно с помощью оператора сравнения**

Но есть способ как это сделать с помощью JSON.stringify

```js
 x = [1,2,3];
 y = [1,2,3];
 z = [1,2,3,4,5];
 
 console.log(JSON.stringify(x) === JSON.stringify(y) );
  console.log(JSON.stringify(x) === JSON.stringify(z) );
```

[А также с помощью болле сложного кода на js (ссылка)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1144249/2360072)

**Дополнительно**

Операторы сравнения в JavaScript

```
==  equal to
=== equal value and equal type
!=  not equal
!== not equal value or not equal type
>   greater than
<   less than
>=  greater than or equal to
<=  less than or equal to
?   ternary operator
```

[типы данных в JavaScript](https://learn.javascript.ru/types-intro)